# Google Sankey Diagram - Highlight whole flow from specific node

Tags: google-visualization, data-visualization, sankey-diagram

i have google sankey diagram

```js
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['sankey']});      
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'From');
    data.addColumn('string', 'To');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Weight');
    data.addRows([
      [ 'A', 'X', 5 ],
      [ 'A', 'Y', 7 ],
      [ 'A', 'Z', 6 ],
      [ 'B', 'X', 2 ],
      [ 'B', 'Y', 9 ],
      [ 'B', 'Z', 4 ],
      [ 'Z', 'H', 4 ],
    ]);

    // Sets chart options.
    var options = {
      width: 600,
      sankey: {
        node: {
          interactivity: true
        }
    }
    };

    // Instantiates and draws our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.Sankey(document.getElementById('sankey_basic'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="sankey_basic" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

I've set option - `node interactivity: true`, which does following thing: When you click on the node, it highlights paths which goes into this node and which goes from this node.

But the case is, I want to highlight whole path. For example in my snippet, if you click node 'A', it must highlight also 'Z' - 'H' path. Is it possible to do such thing? Thank you in advance.

Comment: nothing out of the box, you could try to highlight manually, on the chart's select event, but would be difficult, and the chart would revert when the user hovers over the chart...

Comment: That's bad... Okay, thank's anyway